# Storing and accessing javascript in xml with query

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'd like to store javascript in xml and place it into documents when appropriate. But it seems the xml parser strips out all of the text between special characters (<,>,",'). Is there anything I can do to make it stop doing that. It's not practical to go in and escape them. Code here:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "/mwebphoto/xml/albums.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('album').each(function(){
            var xmlAlbum= $(this)
            var xmlTitle = $(this).find('title').text();
            var xmlEmbedCode = $(this).find('embedCode').text();
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a very odd approach and one that is potentially insecure. I would imagine that for most cases like this you wouldn't need an entire embed code, but rather just some values in the embed code that change from one item to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is syntactically wrong: a semicolon is missing after the `xmlAlbum` declaration and you haven't closed the iterator (did you just miss to copy it into your question ?).

to store special chars in xml you have to represent them properly:

- `<` -> `&#x3c;`
- `>` -> `&#x3e;`
- `&` -> `&#x26;`
- `'` -> `&#x27;`
- `"` -> `&#x22;`

note however that the quotes may be used verbatim - just make sure that they don't interfere with the delimiting quotes of attribute values.

another option would be to wrap the offending text portions into cdata sections ( `<![CDATA[...]]>`. this method relieves you from using the abovementioned encoding.

there is another approach you might wish to follow: embed your js code in `script` blocks assigned a mime type different from `text/javascript`. the blocks will be adopted to the dom and will be accessible eg. through suitable jquery selectors.

caveat: i haven't tried that method with pure js, user agents might be too intelligent executing the code in spite of the mime type.